# Xamarin: Java.IO.IOException Message=Cleartext HTTP traffic to myapi.azurewebsites.net not permitted

Tags: xamarin.android

I recently upgraded to the latest version of Xamarin 4.5.0.356.  This forced me to change my Android build version to 9.0.

Since then, whenever I call my test Api I get:

```
Java.IO.IOException   Message=Cleartext HTTP traffic to myapi.azurewebsites.net not permitted
```

I realise that API's should all be http**S** but this is a test one (owned by me).

I searched the web (stack overflow) and it was suggested that I add the following to AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
</manifest>
```

and then add a Resources/xml/network_security_config.xml file containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">myapi.azurewebsites.net</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

However, I still get the error on the first call to the API.  (iOS version works fine)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try add a base-config in your network_security_config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">myapi.azurewebsites.net</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: I did not get chance to try both base and domain config options.  Instead we changed the site to httpS and it all works now.

Comment: Https is always the best choice, good to hear that you solved the problem.